# Removing all Characters after a Certain Character From Filenames

Tags: regex, batch-rename

I have been trying to Remove all characters after a certain Character in My Multiple File names

What I am trying to do is :

`test1234 - 15-03-16 - this-is-a-test.mp4` -----> `test1234 - 15-03-16 - this is a test.mp4`

`test1234 - 12-02-18 - this-is-another-test.mp4` -----> `test1234 - 12-02-18 - this is another test.mp4`

That is remove all `-` in `this-is-a-test` as well as `this-is-another-test`
(I have around 100 files named in the same way)

I used Bulk Rename Utility and it's Regex Function

```
RegEx (1)
Match: ^([^-])
Replace: \1
```

I have no idea about Regex,I made the above code after seeing a similar post to mine...Unfortunately it didn't work in my case

It removed all `-` From Filenames

Is there any way I could achieve this..any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: `(.*)-.*\w+` - Does this work for you ? https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/7

Comment: I edited my question now..earlier it was a bit confusing..Thank you for responding

Comment: It's still pretty confusing. So is the goal _not_ to remove '-' from filenames, as in the example? Can you give an example of what it is you do want?

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove all `-` from the last part of the file name along with the resolution ?

Comment: Yes..I edited my question again
I hope it will give clarity now..Thanks

Comment: You might use`\b-\b` and replace with a space ` `. Add the global flag.

Comment: Try matching a hyphen while asserting only non whitespace chars followed by .mp4 at the right, and replace with a space `-(?=\S*\.mp4$)` https://regex101.com/r/hC7RgB/1

Comment: Hey..that Solved my Problem by Half
Thank you @PoulBak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lookaheads are supported, you can match a hyphen while asserting what follows are 0+ non whitespace chars followed by .mp4 at the end of the string.

In the replacement use a space.

```
-(?=\S*\.mp4$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHiV4L/1)

Or a broader match:

```
-(?=\S*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4t9J2u/1)

Comment: Thank you very much..that solved all my problems

Is there any books or something where I can learn atleast the basics of regex during this time of Pandemic!

Comment: You are welcome. These are for example great resources https://www.rexegg.com/ and https://www.regular-expressions.info/